# How to install a ruby gem in Jenkins?

Tags: ruby, jenkins, rubygems, rvm

I'm looking for a way to install `ruby`, `gem` and finally a specific `gem` (`sass` & `compass` actually) only with the `jenkins` account (which is not `root`).

I had a look at [rvm](https://rvm.io/) but it tries to do a `sudo` to install ruby in "Single-User" mode (trying to `apt-get` it), so it fails because we are not in interactive bash, and my jenkins user would not have rights to install stuffs in Ubuntu anyways.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

1. sudo su -l
2. rvm use $your_ruby
3. gem install sass
4. chown -R jenkins:jenkins $sass_install_directory

this is probably the simplest way.

If you're trying to do this multiple times, it's better to change the rvm gems folder's permissions so that the jenkins user owns it - root would still be able to install there.

Comment: Actually I'm looking for a way to do it without accessing to the server using root, only using Jenkins user in a build task... Like I can do it to install the version of Node or Maven I want

Answer (score 0):

Does the machine have compiler tools installed (`gcc`, etc)? At certain point in the reqirements list it will be necessary to install *some* binary packages using `root`... It would save a *lot* of hassle if you could install a binary package `ruby`.

However if the compiler toolchain is available, one can always compile `ruby` as non-`root` by specifying `configure` parameters. Note, that you will have to download the source code and compile all the other libraries it depends on as well.

Installing gems for a given user is trivial, just run `gem install` as non-`root` and it will install the runnable commands under `$HOME/bin`.
(The actual gems will be under `$HOME/.gem`)